# What is that stretched line in my uv map?

Tags: uv, edit-mode

What is this stretched out line when I UV unwrap? Also, how do I display a heat map in Blender 2.9? It's not showing up under display (see screenshot below).

[image: orc mesh in edit mode - unwrapped]

Comment: This line is an edge. You probably made some modifications to your mesh after unwrapping it, that's what's causing the line which is just an edge that is stretched. I don't know what you mean by heat map tho.

Comment: There must be a seam missing somewhere, thus this connexion between 2 faces (or more)

Comment: If you check the icon with the two arrows at the left-hand end of the UV editor toolbar you can then select the vertices at each end of those lines in the UV window and see what is selected on your object in the 3D viewport.

Comment: @mqbaka mqbaka I suspect she means the UV stretch overlay: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209702/where-did-the-uv-stretch-option-go-in-2-9

Comment: @JohnEason Ah ok, I suspected that too but I wasn't sure so..